# Why doesn't my Wordpress shortcode function work for my custom post types?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to create a shortcode that will display one post (selected by the user). I have a function that works for regular posts but it doesn't display anything for my custom post types (or pages for that matter) and I am not quite sure why.

The shortcode:

```
[post_feat p=2512]
```

This is my shortcode code:

```
add_shortcode('post_feat', 'post_shortcode_query');
function post_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
  extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '1',
   'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'product-reviews' ),
    ), $atts));

  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query($atts);
  $output = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts())
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
            $posts->the_post();
            $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
            $out = '<div class="featured-post-menu">
            <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="' . get_the_title() . '">
            
                <div class="ft-img-post">
                    <img src="'. $feat_image . '">
                </div>
                <h2 class="aside">'.get_the_title() .'</h2>';
                // add here more...
            $out .='</a></div>';

    endwhile;
  else
    return; // no posts found

  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

This is my custom post type code:

```
register_post_type( 'product-reviews',
        // CPT Options
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Product Reviews' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Product Review' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product-reviews'),
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', ),
                'taxonomies'          => array('topics', 'category' ),
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                  
            )

        );
```

If anyone has any insight on why this isn't working for me I would very much appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase - I tried creating a new function for the just the custom post types, also made some changes to the CPT functions as I thought something there might have been the issue, but I so far haven't been able to figure out why this works for regular posts but not CPTs. Do you have any debugging suggestions?

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it. This could contain attempts like running XDebug, dumping variables,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shortcode_atts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) outputs an array, it does not alter the existing array.

You're then extracting the keys as values.

Change the code to the code below to get it working.

```
add_shortcode('post_feat', 'post_shortcode_query');
function post_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
  extract(shortcode_atts(array('p'=>-1), $atts));
  $args=array( 
   'posts_per_page' => '1',
   'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'product-reviews' ),
   'p'=>$p,
    );
  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
  $output = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts())
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
            $posts->the_post();
            $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
            $out = '<div class="featured-post-menu">
            <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="' . get_the_title() . '">
            
                <div class="ft-img-post">
                    <img src="'. $feat_image . '">
                </div>
                <h2 class="aside">'.get_the_title() .'</h2>';
                // add here more...
            $out .='</a></div>';

    endwhile;
  else
    return; // no posts found

  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```